# Getting width and height of a dynamic image

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have a `img` tag embedded inside a hidden `div`. When the user clicks on a dynamic hyperlink, having the image name, the image has to be showed in a modal window. For positioning the div inside the modal window, the image height is required. But when the hyperlink is clicked, the after the `src` is assigned, the height is coming as `0`. So the image cannot be aligned in the middle. Please help me to get the width of the image before the it is shown in the browser.

```
<div id="imgFullView" class="modal_window imgFullView">
    <img alt="Loading..." id="imgFull" />
</div>

function ShowImage(imgSrc) {
    $("#imgFull").attr("src", imgSrc);
    alert($("#imgFull").height());
    $("#imgFullView").width($("#imgFull").width());
    $("#imgFullView").height($("#imgFull").height());
    show_modal('imgFullView', true);
}
```

This `showimage` method would be called `onclick` of the hyperlink.
Thanks in Advance...

Solution that worked for me, after all your professional guidance...

```
 function ShowImage(imgSrc) {
    $("#imgFull").removeAttr("src"); //To remove the height and width of previously showed imaged from img tag.
    $("#imgFull").attr("src", imgSrc);
    $("#imgFullView").width(document.getElementById("imgFull").width);
    $("#imgFullView").height(document.getElementById("imgFull").height);
    show_modal('imgFullView', true);
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this.

```
    var img = $("imgFull")[0]; // Get my img elem
    var real_width, real_height;
    $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
        .attr("src", $(imgFull).attr("src"))
        .load(function() {
            real_width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
            real_height = this.height; // work for in memory images.
        });
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm, the problem is that you can't know the size of an image that hasn't been loaded yet. Try this:

```
function ShowImage(imgSrc) {
  $("#imgFull").attr("src", imgSrc);
  $("#imgFull").load(function(){  //This ensures image finishes loading
     alert($("#imgFull").height());
     $("#imgFullView").width($("#imgFull").width());
     $("#imgFullView").height($("#imgFull").height());
     show_modal('imgFullView', true);
  });
}
```

With `.load()` we ensure the image finishes loading before trying to get its size()

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: $("#imgFull").height() will return 0 when the image is hidden, you must use native js to get the height/width

Comment: U are right but kind of wrong.. but DR. Molle's thought gave me an idea. Actually, when i tried document.getelementbyid().width, it is not 0 before .load(). It had a value. since it was hidden, width() gave 0. That part is absolutely fantastic. I used native js to grab the width.  And for dynamic loading, i had the remove the src attr and add it again to reject the width set by preivous image.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me in the past:

```
function ShowImage(imgSrc){
 $('<img id="imgFull" />').bind('load',
    function(){
        if ( !this.complete || this.naturalWidth == 0 ) {
            $( this ).trigger('load');      
        } else {
            $( this ).appendTo('#imgFullView')
$('#imgFullView').width(this.naturalWidth).height(this.naturalHeight);
        }    
    }).attr("src",imgSrc);   
}

$(document).ready(function(){ ShowImage('http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png') });
```

demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jyVFc/4/

Comment: the answer is correct if we use a this.width. but it has extra  logic of loading the image in memory using jquery just o grab the width, when it is already available in this.width of the img tag. But the this.width is the exact solution i wanted...

Comment: Ahh okay, I actually misread your question as well. Glad Chandresh was able to give you the answer you were looking for though :)