# Image height using jQuery .attr gets the size of the parent element, rather than the actual image height attribute in Chrome

Tags: jquery, dom

I have an image which is inside a regular DIV. Let's call it DIV b. Above DIV b there is another DIV, which I will call DIV a. DIV a has overflow: hidden. Here is the code:

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <img id="image" src="http://fgjdfgsjh.com/images/hghgajfhsd.jpg" height="186" width="900">
  </div>
</div>
```

... here some important CSS for this example:

```
#a {overflow: hidden; height: 128px;}
```

... and finally some .js:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var test = $('#image').attr('height');
     alert(test);
  });
</script>
```

As you can see, the image has the height attribute already set on it. My script (jQuery) needs to grab that information, but when I use $('#image').attr('height'), the script is delivering me the number 128, which is the height of the #a element that contains #b and the image, rather than the expected height of the image, which is 186 and is set as an attribute in the HTML.

This is happening in Chrome. Firefox can get the right height of the image (186, instead of 128).

How can I get the actual original height of the image in Chrome? Is it possible to do it with plain simple jQuery, or do I have to do some gimmick (like reloading the image in a separate object and checking its original height)?

Comment: unable to produce this scenario, your code works absolutely fine with no issues. `alerting 186` see this: http://jsfiddle.net/QhEzB/

Answer (score 1):

CSS is generally preferred to the `height` attribute. To use jQuery, use [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$('#image').css('height');
```

Which will return `186px` here. If you only want `186`, use [`.height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

```
$("#image").height();
```

Comment: Ouch, this is weird. I thought you had nailed it, but Chrome has an erratic behavior on this. I am refreshing this script over and over and... guess what? Sometimes it will pop 128px, sometimes it will pop 186px! This isn't consistent. Is there any other way? Looks I will have to load the image sepparetely...

Comment: are you sure height/width attributes are deprectated for IMG tags?

Comment: @MarcosBuarque Try using CSS instead.
@A.Wolff My mistake. I checked [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#attr-dim-height), and `height`/`width` are still valid. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mooseman, this doesn't work on Chrome. As I have posted on the comment above, Chrome will throw inconsistent information. Looks like there is no other way, I have to dynamically load an image. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has an erratic behavior on this issue. I tried code provided by @Mooseman, but when refreshing the page over and over, sometimes the script would pop 128px, sometimes it would pop 186px!

Looks like the only way to do this consistently is by loading the image dynamically. I have borrowed code from here: "[getting width and height of a dynamic image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606262/getting-width-and-height-of-a-dynamic-image#tab-top)".

In the end, the code is:

```
  $('<img/>').attr('src', $('#image').attr('src')).load(function() {
    // Then just get the resulting loaded image height by using:
    var myHeight = this.height;
  }
```

Comment: This may work to get the height, but is bad practice because the image will not be loaded until after the document is ready. If the image is part of the HTML, it can be loaded at the same time as the JS/CSS files.