# Js - How to get image size every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have this bit of `Jquery` code, the purpose of the code is to show an image that fits within the dimensions of my screen. The images are loaded dynamically ie: they will be generated when needed. The problem I have is that when I load the images the first time the `height` and `width` of the image is `0`. Is there a way for me to be sure to always get the size of the image?

my code so far looks like this:

```
    var parent = document.getElementById('gallery-lightBox-large'),
        image = originalImages[currentIndex],
        original = document.createElement('img');

    parent.innerHTML = '';

    original.src = image.Url;

    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight * 0.8,    //  Allow for 10% margin
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.8;      //  Allow for 10% margin

    original.style.opacity = '0';
    original.style.position = 'absolute';
    original.style.zIndex = '-99';
    parent.appendChild(original);
    //console.info('original : ' + original.clientHeight, original.clientWidth);

    var elem = document.createElement('img');
    elem.src = image.Url;
    elem.clientHeight = original.clientHeight;
    elem.clientWidth = original.clientWidth;

    var width,
        height;

    if (windowHeight < windowWidth) {   //  Landscape mode
        if (original.clientWidth > windowWidth) {
            width = windowWidth;
        } else {
            width = original.clientWidth;
        }

        if (original.clientHeight > windowHeight) {
            width = undefined;
            height = windowHeight;
        } else {
            height = original.clientHeight;
        }
    } else {    //  Portrait mode
        if (original.clientHeight > windowHeight) {
            height = windowHeight;
        } else {
            height = original.clientHeight;
        }

        if (original.clientWidth > windowWidth) {
            height = undefined;
            width = windowWidth;
        } else {
            width = original.clientWidth;
        }
    }

    if (width != undefined) {
        if (width === 0) {
            width = 200;
        }
        elem.width = width;
    }

    if (height != undefined) {
        if (height === 0) {
            height = 200;
        }
        elem.height = height;
    }

    parent.appendChild(elem);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606262/getting-width-and-height-of-a-dynamic-image

Comment: Did you try using css for this? I believe you could use viewport units to get much faster and more consistent behaviour.

Comment: @MartinGottweis: You were right giving the image an `max-height` and `max-width` fixed the problem, don't know why I didn't think of that ^^

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way to check the image size once is loaded

```
var img= document.getElementById('imgid');

img.onload = function () {
    alert(img.width + "," + img.height);       
};
```

Comment: That would do the trick. If I were to go for a `JavaScript` solution I would have used this, but if I can keep as much design in `css` I'll do that. +1 for nice solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

After advice from [Martin Gottweis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4742670/martin-gottweis) (Whom are more than welcome to make an answer for me to accept ;-) )

My solution looks like this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('gallery-lightBox-large'),
    image = originalImages[currentIndex];
var elem = document.createElement('img');
elem.src = image.Url;
parent.appendChild(elem);
```

with this css

```
#gallery-lightBox-large img {
    max-height:70vh;
    max-width: 70vw;
}
```